# ajax отправка изображения

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь отправит изображения на сторонний сервер делаю так:

```js
 $('#imgFile').on('change', function () {
      var input = $("#imgFile");
      var fd = new FormData;
      fd.append('imgfile', input.prop('files')[0]);
      $('.products-imagesearch').html('<center>loading...</center>');
      $.ajax({
       url: 'https://s.taobao.com/image',
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       type: 'POST',
       success: function (data) {
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(result.name != 'undefined'){
         alert(result.name);
        }
       }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('imgFile').click(); return false;" id="btnUpload"> Загрузить фотографию</a>
    <input id="imgFile" name="imgFile" type="file" style="display:none">
    <div class='products-imagesearch'></div>
```

Такой вот код у меня консоль ругает на ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ведь здесь этот код отлично работает.

Comment: `crossDomain: true`?

Comment: тоже самое ошибка.

Comment: ну, вам пишут, что в списке допустимых заголовков запроса к этому домену не может быть заголовка `X-Requested-With`. этот заголовок добавляет jquery. поищите способ его не посылать

Comment: попробуйте удалить этот заголовок в `beforeSend`

Comment: А может быт это связано тем что сайт не `https`

Comment: у меня с сайта стековерфлоу работает, и из консоли http-шного сайта тоже работает. не знаю что посоветовать

Comment: Может конфликт с другими js скриптами?